# incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'int' when converting char* to char* lowercase

Tags: c, string, char

I have this annoying warning when I go to compile my code. I'm trying to take a `char *` and convert it to lower case before I run it through a test. My code compiles just fine but I want to learn how to get rid of this warning. Other posts with this same error don't provide me with what I need to change to remove this error.

```
//convert to lower case
char *c = "WORD TO LOWER";
char *s[testWordLen];
for (int i = 0; i < testWordLen; i++)
{
    s[i] =  tolower((unsigned char) c[i]);
}
```

An explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be great too.

Comment: `char *s[testWordLen];` -> `char s[testWordLen];` The first is an array of pointers, the second is an array of characters.

Comment: No, sorry, your code is not "compiling just fine" — that "annoying warning" is a serious problem!  There are two ways of working with strings in C: using arrays of `char`, or pointers to `char`.  But you've got an array of pointer to `char`, which is neither!

Comment: Thanks @RetiredNinja. I'll change this and see how it runs.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I did not downvote.) I see "downvote" as kind of misleading, however, it reduces your reputation. If you hover on the down triangle, you read "This question does not show any research effort; ..." and this is a fair reason to downvote. Even for novices it is expected to show that they have read and tried to understand (in this case) the warning or error message. You can do this by explaining what you think is warned about, and why you think it is no problem.

Comment: "_Compiles fine_" and "_annoying warning_" are also signs of not understanding the issue. If the compiler were a person, it would be the one who is annoyed by the probable wrong code, repeatedly presented ot it, but luckily it is kind enough to raise its hand, without getting tired. ;-) See the compiler as your friend, sedulously trying to help you.

Comment: To save you from bugs like this one, follow this advise: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Comment: I posted the answer in the comments to the answering box for future viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a two-dimensional array using `char *s[testWordLen];`; that is, a pointer to an array of chars. When you dereference it like this: `s[i] =  tolower((unsigned char) c[i]);`, you assign a single character to an array.

The fix is this: declare the variable as `char s[testWordLen];`